# find email by account using active record ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-midrange

I am trying to refactor a model using best practices, which I assume would be Active Record.

```
 class WEBOEL23 < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection "as400_#{RAILS_ENV}"
 set_table_name "WEBOEL23"  

    def get_email 
      @weboe123 = WEBOEL23.EMAL23    
      where @weboel23
 end
end
```

I am calling this in models/order.rb In order.rb I am looking for an email out of the weboel23 table.(which is a logical file from a AS400) When this code is executed it returns a NameError (uninitialized constant Order::EMAL23)

```
 if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS" or sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD" 

if approval0!=""  

                            Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(Weboel23.get_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "DIST Confirmation-0 ", email_details)

end
```

I have tried all of the suggestions below and yes I am still learning but I really need some guidance to get past this error

Comment: I think you need to pause at the moment, look for an introductory tutorial to rails, ignore whatever you think you know ATM so you can absorb new information, then you would realize you are doing a whole lot wrongly, the code might work but it's not rails like

Comment: that is the reason for wanting to refactor. I have inherited this app and want to get it up to speed using proper methods. I am currently doing tutorials (rails for zombies 2)but have to keep progressing on the project as well.

Comment: You haven't even asked a direct question, except for maybe "should weboel23.rb be a controller?" But you didn't post that code so we won't know.

Comment: the top code section is weboel23.rb - updated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from which language you come from but you definitively don't use the ruby and rails Style.

- First of all, you use `find_email_by_account act223` and you assign a
  variable so why to you call this method.
- Secondly, `d= ""`, what is `d`. In ruby, and in programation in
  general, is better to use explicit name.
- For `!act223.blank?`, there is this method `act223.present?`.
- What is `s` in `s = @email.where ["EMAL23=?" ]`?
- Where come from variable `@email` or `act223`?

For you error, a file called `weboel23` must define a model called `Weboel123`.

You should probably do an instance method callable like this `@account.email`.

I suggest to build a model like this :

```
class WEBOEL23 < ActiceRecord::Base
  establish_connection "as400_#{RAILS_ENV}"
  set_table_name "WEBOEL23"

  def email
    WEBOEL23.where(ACT223: act223).first.email
  end
end
```

So you can use it like this :

```
@weboel23.email
```

I don't know if this is the best practice because I don't know what is ACT223 or weboel23.

**I agree with the comment of @bjhaid. Take a pause and read about ruby and rails.**

Comment: originally the model looked like---------
def self.get_email_by_account2 act223
  d = ""
        if !act223.blank?  
         s = Weboel23.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 emal23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = ? " , act223]      
  if !s[2].nil?               
              d= s[2].emal23
              end

--------I was attempting to reactor it using active record intead of writing the query by hand

Comment: still getting the LoadError so I assume it is due to the way I am using the the instance method-----------------------------------Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(@weboel23.email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "DIST Confirmation-0 ", email_details) Am I calling the instance correctly in this case?

Comment: I was able to get past the initial error (syntax) the current error is NoMethodError (Undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass): - does this mean that the email record is returning blank?

Comment: You must to do `@weboe123 = WEBOEL23`. But seriously, it take about 2 to 4 weeks to learn Rails. Take the time to do it.

Comment: I don't think than you give the line and the file where the error is appening. You should have a trace with a line and a path, please, can you provide this file?

Comment: it is  app/models/order.rb:385 which is the line I was modifying  Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(Weboel23.get_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "DIST Confirmation-0 ", email_details)

Comment: I am no longer getting any errors in the logs but it is still not pulling the email from WEBOEL23 so I tried renaming the logical file to Webemails in models/weboel23.rb. I also tried using ACT223.find_by(:email => $EMAL23 all of these seem to function without error but not pulling email not sure what would cause this there is valid data and I can connect to the table

Comment: Are you using [a mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)?

Comment: yes in the models/order.rb I am calling the mailer lie this: Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email($get_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "DIST Approval-0 ", email_details)

Comment: I think you should use a standard mailer like showed in the guide : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html. In addition, you don't need to have `$` before a variable.

Comment: i thought that was the difference between a local and global variable?

Comment: when I make it a local variable: Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(Get_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "DIST Approval-0 ", email_details) I get the undefined local variable or method when I make it a global variable it does not throw an error, is it just dying silently?

Comment: You can know it by adding this `puts $email`. Anyway, to use global variable is not a good idea. You should use a instance variable and you must to specify it. If your method `get_email` works, it should return something, so you can do this `Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(@weboel23.email....)` If you call the method in the model, you must replace `@weboel23` by self or nothing.

Comment: Let me see if I understood you correctly?  I added the following to models/weboel23.rb-- 
def self.weboel23
    atweboel23  end
     
   def self.get_email(account0)
   atwebemails = WEBEMAIL.EMAL23
   User.find_by(:email => atwebemails)   end
and then I am calling it like this:Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(atweboel23.get_email, "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "DIST Approval-0 ", email_details)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use the `ActiveMailer::Base` class as specified in the guide. Please, take the time to read the guide.

Comment: in the mailer.rb I am using class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base 
Should the calls that I am making in the weboel23.rb be inside the mailer.rb instead?

Comment: First of all, you must to check if a email address is returned. Do something like `puts get_email` and see if the value is what you except. If it is, you must to deliver a mail. Don't forget to call the `deliver` on your mailer.

Comment: I am unable to get a value returned so I assume that @webemails is not working but I am not sure what I should try next as I am making no progress on this??

Comment: I think you must take your time and learn how to make a rails project with a demo application.

Comment: yes I am taking courses and learning and creating demo on the weekend but I still have to keep making progress on this project as well.